# Get only one field in protocol buffer without deserializing whole object in java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have POJO that serialized with protobuf. This object has many fields. I want to check one field. Is it possible to deserialize only one filed without deserializing the whole object in Java? I think it is probable in Python.

Comment: You could create a twin `message` that *just* has the property you're interested in, and deserialize *that*? However, depending on the implementation, it may still do work to store the unexpected fields for round-trip purposes. Another approach is to use the raw parser/reader API, but that depends on how complex your model is.

Comment: if you know the tag id, CodedInputStream works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

- I have already implemented this in Scala and published as a library to the Maven central under:

  - [cz.jkozlovsky:scala-protobuf-field-extractor_${scalaVersion}](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:cz.jkozlovsky%20AND%20a:scala-protobuf-field-extractor_*)

In case you are comfortable with Scala, the usage of the library is explained [within the README](https://github.com/jirislav/scala-protobuf-extractor#usage).

- Also, [the tests](https://github.com/jirislav/scala-protobuf-extractor/blob/c9e87235bccbddc885c496bad277fc596988f5b3/src/test/scala/cz/jkozlovsky/scala/protobuf/field/extractor/FieldExtractorTest.scala) might give you a good idea of how to use the API.

---

In case you need Java native solution, you can easily implement it yourself.
For details, see the [staticExtract](https://github.com/jirislav/scala-protobuf-extractor/blob/c9e87235bccbddc885c496bad277fc596988f5b3/src/main/scala/cz/jkozlovsky/scala/protobuf/field/extractor/FieldExtractor.scala) method.

Here is a Scala snippet of the implementation (any decent IDE should automatically convert this to Java while pasting):

```scala
  def staticExtract[T](codedInputStream: CodedInputStream, fieldDescriptor: FieldDescriptor, extractionMethod: CodedInputStream => T): T = {
    while (!codedInputStream.isAtEnd) {
      if (WireFormat.getTagFieldNumber(codedInputStream.readTag()) == fieldDescriptor.getNumber) {
        return extractionMethod.apply(codedInputStream)
      } else codedInputStream.skipField(codedInputStream.getLastTag)
    }
    fieldDescriptor.getDefaultValue.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```

- all it does, is it iterates over the input stream until either:

  - the queried field is found

    - then the provided extraction method is applied upon the current stream state (e.g. `CodedInputStream.readBool()`)
    - it is important to note, that the `tag` read by the `CodedInputStream` contains both the `fieldNumber` and the `wireType` (as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)), so you have to first extract the `fieldNumber` in order to match it with the `FieldDescriptor`'s number
  - the end is reached

    - in which case, the default value is returned